# padding for links vertical in nav bar

Tags: css, menu, padding, space, nav

I have worked on a new menu for my site, but I cannot seem to arrange for space between the links vertically (*I want more white space between links*) Any advice?

html

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
<li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul.menu
{
list-style-type:none;
list-style-position: inside;
margin:0;
padding:0;
padding-bottom: 1cm;
}



.menu li a, .menu li a:visited
{
padding:12px 0 0 0px;
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-weight:700;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#09F;
text-align:center;
padding:3px;
text-decoration:none;

}

.menu li a:hover, menu li a:active {
background-color:#666;
}
```

As you can see I have attempted the gaps with a piece of css: {padding:12px 0 0 0px;} but no luck.... everything else works *fine* - see fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/DCxvy/

Comment: .menu li a, .menu li a:visited has two padding define, one 12px first, then 3px right after. remove it all, just add line-height to your ul, (greater than your font-size)

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding line-height mixed with some below answers - it worked fine - see fiddle of final method http://jsfiddle.net/gzN9N/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchors are by default inline elements. To add certain padding values, you need to render them as inline block-level elements. Add `display: block` to your anchor styles:

```
.menu li a { display: inline-block }
```

Also, you should note that your `.menu li a` style has two entries for `padding`. The latter one (setting padding to `3px` on all sides) is overriding your earlier definition.

Here's a [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DCxvy/2/).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you want to insert space vertically between links.
For that, all you have to do is:

```
.menu li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

[fiddle with the margin solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/Kb7ev/)

On the other hand, if you want the background of your menu to remain the shade of blue it is and have the colour change on hover then here is the fiddle for that.
I have also refactored your css to arrange rules in a more intuitive manner.

[fiddle with the menu background as a solid colour without white line breaks.](http://jsfiddle.net/eEXBw/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I might change to a one width setting